# How can i get values of parameters using postman?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, visual-studio, express

I am working on Node JS and PostgreSQL and I am creating REST web service using this. I have created a post method and calling web service through POSTMAN but unable to get parameter values in my function. Web service inserting null value in my PostgreSQL table. I am using Visual studio 2015 unable to debug code. How can I achieve this ?

queries.js

```
var promise = require('bluebird');

var options = {
    // Initialization Options
    promiseLib: promise
};

var pgp = require('pg-promise')(options);
var connectionString = 'postgres://test:12345@localhost:8080/test';
var db = pgp(connectionString);


function getAllTask(req, res, next) {
    debugger;
    db.any('select * from tasklist')
        .then(function (data) {

            res.status(200)
                .json({
                    status: 'success',
                    message: 'Retrieved ALL puppies',
                    data: data

                });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            return next(err);
        });
}


function addTask(req, res, next) {
    debugger;
    //var task_name = req.param('task_name');
    //var task_type = req.param('task_type');
    var task_name = req.body.task_name;
    var task_type = req.body.task_type;
    console.log(req.body);
    db.func('inserttask', [task_name, task_type])
        .then(function () {
            res.status(200)
                .json({
                    status: 'success',
                    message: 'Inserted one task'
                });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            return next(err);
        });
}


module.exports = {
    getAllTask: getAllTask,
    addTask: addTask
};
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../queries');

/* GET home page. */

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/api/tasklist', db.getAllTask);
router.post('/api/addtask', db.addTask);

module.exports = router;
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon iblic
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: console.log(req.body) see if you get anything in the body if not then check whether you are putting things properly in the body part of postman. req.body gives you the elements you stored in body.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are already using express js as framework for node js.

First of all you need to install body-parser module from npm:-

```
$ npm install body-parser --save
```

Once you have installed body-parser, add following code once after you have defined app variable:-

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // to support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // to support encoded bodies
```

Now you can access your post request body paramters as req.body.task_name and req.body.task_type

Hope it works and I am sorry if I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks Siddhart for your reply. I have already used this in my code but nothing happen. If I am using get method then I am getting values from parameters like this var task_name = req.param('task_name'); but I failed to get values in post method.

Comment: Are you using express js? Could you please share your code snippet of server set up

Comment: the way you have written queries.js is incorrect, you should be passing req, res objects to addTask function, then you will be able to extract req.body

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Content-Type: application/json inside Headers when you send request through POSTMAN.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Jeton for your reply. Now its giving me SyntaxError: Unexpected token -. 400 Bad Request in postman

Comment: in Postman, in the body section your structure should be like this :

{
 "task_name": "Test",
 "task_type": "Type"
}